# Bootstrap modal não funciona no navegador chrome

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com um problema no meu sistema web feito em `PHP/Laravel`:

Tenho um laço de repetição e dentro deste laço tenho um botão para cada item, que abre um modal do bootstrap, da seguinte forma:

```html
<button name = "btnAbrirDetalhes" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#modalDetalhesPedido" class = "btn btn-primary" data-id="{{$sanduiche->id}}">Detalhes</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalDetalhesPedido" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style = "height: 900px">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style = "font-weight: bold">Detalhes do Pedido (Nome do pedido)</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" style = "height: 195px;">
            <p name="id"></p>
            <h1 id = "nome">Nome</h1>
            <h2 id = "preco">Preco: R$ 20,00</h2>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "" value = "bacon">Bacon<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "" value = "bacon">Mussarela<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "" value = "bacon">Tomate<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "" value = "bacon">Alface<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "" value = "bacon">Salsicha<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "" value = "bacon">Presunto<br>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Estes botões quando usados no Chrome, não fazem absolutamente nada.
Quando vou para o firefox, eles funcionam.

Alguém consegue me dizer o por que disso?

> OBS: não posso utilizar este sistema no firefox porque acontece outros
>   bugs nele

Comment: Tem algum erro no console?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nas versões do código Bootstrap se são as mesmas, o CSS e o JS, e também vê se você colocou o JQuery direito antes do Bootstrap etc.

Comment: @LucasCosta Sem nenhum erro no console. Um fato interessante é que no chrome eu tenho outro botão, independente desses, que abre um outro modal, e ele funciona sem problemas.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway Sim, são as mesmas e o JQuery está antes do Bootstrap

Acredito que seja algum problema com o fato de ter dois modais na mesma página, mas ambos têm ids diferentes. Eu fiz um teste colocando dois modais em uma mesma página usando um arquivo html e não tive problemas, mas neste sistema estou com problemas :(

Comment: Outra OBS importante é que estou usando o ubuntu, a versão do chrome aqui está em 49.0, acho que possa ser isso... Não consigo encontrar versões mais recentes pro ubuntu, o chrome não atualiza mais automaticamente, talvez no ubuntu a última versão tenha sido essa...

Comment: @GabrielAugusto Uso a versão `17.10` do Ubuntu e estou com o `Chrome v.56.0.2924.87`. Bastante atrasada a tua versão. Mas a questão do Modal deveria funcionar, independente disso.

Comment: o bootstrap é testado em todos os navegadores antes de ir para produção, com certeza é algum erro no seu código, qual a versão do Bootstrap está usando? a 3 ou a 4?

Comment: além disso, cada modal tem que ser disparado por seu próprio botão, o botão tem que apontar para o ID correspondente à modal.